# I want to use more than one coverage report type inside karma.conf.js

Tags: javascript, karma-runner, code-coverage, istanbul

I am using Karma to write the JS unit test cases and Istanbul to get the coverage report.
My karma.conf.js file is as below -

```
// karma.conf.js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],

    // coverage reporter generates the coverage
    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

    preprocessors: {
      // source files, that you wanna generate coverage for
      // do not include tests or libraries
      // (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
      'test/**/*.js': ['coverage']
    },

    // optionally, configure the reporter
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    }
  });
};
```

Here inside coverageReporter I want to use type 'html' and 'lcov'. To do this i changed it as below --

coverageReporter: {
          type : 'html', 'lcov',
          dir : 'coverage/'
        }

Then I executed `karma start karma.conf.js` but getting below exception --

```
C:\abc\npm-1.4.9>karma start karma.conf.js
05 05 2017 16:57:00.369:ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  C:\abc\npm-1.4.9\karma.conf.js:45
      type : 'html','lcov',
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a configuration with this structure for the coverageReporter property:

```
coverageReporter: {
  // specify a common output directory
  dir: 'coverage/',
  reporters: [
    // reporters not supporting the `file` property
    { type: 'html', subdir: '.' },
    { type: 'lcov', subdir: '.' },

  ]
}
```

This is described in the [readme](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/master/README.md) of karma-coverage.

Comment: This worked but has one side effect. I have mentioned two browsers in karma.conf.js(Chrome and PhantomJs)so normally report is generated for each browser separately but above config is ignoring the browser configuration. Any thoughts about this??? –

Answer (score 0):

Try example below:

```
coverageReporter: {
    reporters: [
        {type: 'html', dir: 'html-coverage'},
        {type: 'lcov'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ohh got it ..so I always need to add these in a combination of type and dir inside curly braces for each reporter type. And I noticed one more thing if we don't mention any dir then by default it creates 'coverage' directory and populates everything inside that. Thanks, @Vlad  !!!